# Getting correlational type tables from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a data frame of the below format.

```
variable  count
a,x        20
a         100
a,y        40
```

I would like to get a matrix similar to correlational matrix but not correlational data. Required matrix is of the below format. This matrix clearly  helps to distinguish the count of each variable. Is it possible to perform such transformations using pandas.

```
a  40  20 100
x   0   0  20
y   0   0  40
   y   x   a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have many ways, one would be to split the strings, pivot and combine with the transpose:

```
df2 = (df['variable']
 .str.split(',', expand=True).ffill(axis=1)
 .join(df.drop(columns='variable'))
 .pivot(0, 1, 'count')
)

out = df2.combine_first(df2.T).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
     a   x   y
a  100  20  40
x   20   0   0
y   40   0   0
```